# Webpack - autoresolving of old libraries

Tags: webpack, dependencies

we are using very old Webpack in my new job, specifically Webpack 2.3.2. But alongside Webpack we are obviously using quite a lot of libraries that are compatible with this version. Is there any way how to autoresolve the libraries with the latest Webpack? Or how to get the latest webpack resolvable with all the libraries? Or some similar solution? I am responsible for UX/UI of our app and I need to upgrade some libraries (and I recommend to upgrade most of them). Thank you very much.

Comment: It would be interesting to know, if "auto resolving" the dependencies would work. What I do - remove all Webpack releated dev depenendencies - and reinstall them in their latest version with Webpack 5. Worked for me ;)